# Producer Consumer using Blocking Queue

Tags: java, producer-consumer, blockingqueue

I have an implementation of Producer/Consumer using Blocking, I start them like this

```
BlockingQueue<Object> myQueue1 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Object>();
new Thread(new SmsInProducer(myQueue1, 100)).start();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
    new Thread(new SmsInConsumer(myQueue1)).start();
}
```

Inside the Producer looks like this

```
public class SmsInProducer implements Runnable {
    protected BlockingQueue queue;
    protected int MAX_RECORDS = 5000;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public SmsInProducer(BlockingQueue theQueue, int maxRecord) {
        this.queue = theQueue;
        this.MAX_RECORDS = maxRecord;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while (true) {
            int totalRecords = MAX_RECORDS - queue.size();
            if (totalRecords > 0) {

            List<Map> tList = Sql.updateTRECEIVE();
            if (tList != null && !tList.isEmpty()) {
                queue.addAll(tList);
            }
        }
        // wait for 1 second
    try { Thread.sleep(Parameter.replyWaitTime * 1000); }   catch(Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

and the Consumer looks like this

```
public class SmsInConsumer implements Runnable {
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
protected BlockingQueue queue;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public SmsInConsumer(BlockingQueue theQueue) {
        this.queue = theQueue;
    }

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (true) {
        try {
        Object obj = queue.take();
                Map map = (Map) obj;

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try { Thread.sleep(Parameter.replyWaitTime * 1000); } catch(Exception e){}
        }
     }
}
```

But after sometime it becomes very slow, is there anyway i can maintain it to be very fast?

Comment: Have you tried a profiler? What part becomes slow?

Comment: remove the calls to `Thread.sleep()`?

Comment: the Thread.sleep() is already 0, so it doesn't wait

Comment: I would use the builtin ExecutorService as you queue and thread pool. I suspect your main delay is in Sql.updateTRECEIVE() or you are getting 100 records every second as the queue fills and empties very quickly. The simplest way to test this is to return the sleep delay to 10 ms and see if its faster.  BTW: For CPU bound tasks, the optimal number of thread can be the number of free CPUs you have e.g. it could be 1 to 10.

Comment: Since the Java API says that Blocking Queue single element simple operations are thread safe, I'm beginning to wonder if it's a machine issue.  How many cores does your machine have?  Does performance stablize if you put in Thread.yeild() calls at the end of each loop?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the sleep in the Consumer, the call to queue.take() will block the Thread until an Objekt becomes available so no need to Sleep.

But, due to it starts fast and get slower over time, try to optimize your Producer.
Try to use more Elements in the Queue, Optimize Sql.updateTRECEIVE(); and Remove the sleep.

Comment: what elements should i use in the Queue?

Comment: What ever Element you need. Just rember creating large Object will slow down the Performance of your Producer. And use Generics to get rid of the @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") and maybe gain some speed (but i dont know if it really matters)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author sakshi
 */
public class BlockingqueueDemo {

    static BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>();

    static class Producer extends Thread {

        BlockingQueue queue;

        public Producer(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
            this.queue = queue;

        }

        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.println("produce" + i);
                try {
                    queue.put(i);
                    Thread.sleep(2000);

               } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(BlockingqueueDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    static class Consumer extends Thread {

        BlockingQueue queue;

        public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
            this.queue = queue;

        }

        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("consume" + queue.take());

                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(BlockingqueueDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Producer produce = new Producer(queue);
        Consumer consume = new Consumer(queue);
        produce.start();
        consume.start();
    }

}

output:

produce0
consume0
produce1
consume1
produce2
consume2
produce3
consume3
produce4
consume4
produce5
consume5
produce6
consume6
produce7
consume7
produce8
consume8
produce9
consume9
```